# cat a file or tags and xargs grep the tags in a file

Tags: linux, grep, xargs

I think it is a simple command only but i simply could not come to a solution

I would like to cat a file with tags (separated by many lines)

**File1**

> aaa 
> bbb
>  ded

and then grep those TAGS(line by line) to a single file, lets call it TargetFile

What I have done is the following:

```
cat File1 | xagrs grep {} TargetFile
```

It does not do a grep on TargetFile. How can I do it?

I am using `mobaxterm` at the moment

Answer (score 3):

```
fgrep -f File1 TargetFile
```

Note also the absence of a Useless Use of Cat.

Answer (score 1):

as usual more than one way to do it:

```
xargs -n 1 grep Targetfile -e < File
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cat File1 | xargs -I {} grep {} TargetFile
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of the files this will run faster:

```
cat File1 | parallel -j0 grep {} TargetFile
```

If the number of tags in File1 is smaller than the number of processes you can run in parallel, then TargetFile will only be read once from disk. If TargetFile is bigger than your disk cache the this is probably a good idea.

To learn more about GNU Parallel see the intro video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpaiGYxkSuQ

Comment: i like to try the parallel. I have seen some example for parallel, i think it quite good tool. But unfortunately, it is not compiled in the mobaxterm. Hopefully, their spider on the web could catch my comment here.

Answer (score -1):

well I think i found the answer after searching in other forums

```
> for i in `cat File1` ; do grep $i TargetFile; done
```

Answer (score -1):

```
cat File1 | while read tag; do grep $tag TargetFile; done
```

Answer (score -1):

```
cat File1 | xagrs -i grep {} TargetFile
```